# Assigning legends manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, charts, legend

I am programming in Visual Studio 12 in Asp.net using C#.

I have a chart that consists of two Series. All the points in the both the series are added like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
  Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Jan", jR);
  Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Feb", fR);
}
```

jR and fR are integer values that are getting assigned as Y values for each X as Jan and Feb.

This same method applies to the second series.

How do I add legends programmatically after adding points to the series?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried Chart2.Legends["Legend2"]?

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how I would use it. At the moment, it shows an Error which says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object operations can be used as a statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more details see [Legends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Jan", i + 10);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Feb", i + 15);
}
// Create a new legend called "Legend1".
chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend("Legend1"));

// Set title
chart1.Legends["Legend1"].Title = "My legend";
// Assign the legend to Series1.
chart1.Series["Series1"].Legend = "Legend1";
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get a legend that consists of 4 things. The first 2 items in the legend are correct and that is what i want but item 3 and 4 in the legend i don't understand where they come from. Any possible cause?

Comment: This code makes this chart http://imageshack.com/a/img854/7722/3fn7.jpg , can you update your code?

Comment: Your answer is correct. But I am still trying to find out where the other two series come up.

Comment: Check this if it helps http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/RSChart/Default%20Legend%20Items.html

Comment: I figured it out. I have named two series "Series1" and "Series2" and and that is the reason why they keep poping up. so now I just disable them and works fine. Thanks again buddy. Really appreciate it :)